# StateElementReferenceException in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting a `StateElementReferenceException` when I try to perform a drag-and-drop action, see the code snippets below. Can anyone please help to solve this with appropriate suggestions and explanations?

```
@Test(priority=4)
public void addUserBySearch() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("btnUserGroup"))).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("btnCreateUG"))).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("textUGName"))).sendKeys("UserGroup:" + Utils.randGen());
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("userSearchField"))).sendKeys("testuser2", Keys.ENTER);
    source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("searchedUserSource")));
    destination = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("userDestination")));
    waitUntilElementVisible(30, source);
    dragAndDrop(source, destination);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("btnScheduleNow"))).click();
}

public void waitUntilElementVisible(int seconds, WebElement element) {
    WebDriverWait explicitWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
    explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}

public void dragAndDrop(WebElement sourceElement, WebElement destinationElement){

    try {
        if (sourceElement.isDisplayed() && destinationElement.isDisplayed()) {
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.dragAndDrop(sourceElement, destinationElement).build().perform();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Element not found to drag and drop");
        }
    }
    catch (StaleElementReferenceException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}



btnUserGroup = //*[text()='User Groups']
btnCreateUG = //*[@id='stage']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/a
textUGName = //input[@id='user_group_name']
btnScheduleNow = //*[text()='Schedule Now']
userDestination = //*[@class='ConnectedList ConnectedListAdded']/div[2]/ul
userSearchField = //div[@class='ConnectedListConnectedListSelect']/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input
searchedUserSource = //div[@class='ConnectedList ConnectedListSelect']/div[2]/ul/li/span[5]
```

**Exception:**

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
>       Command duration or timeout: 10.28 seconds

Comment: what element is giving you the exception?

Comment: at com.suite.regression.RegressionSuiteBase.waitUntilElementVisible(RegressionSuiteBase.java:26)
 at com.suite.regression.UserGroup.addUserBySearch(UserGroup.java:60) I think "source" element

Comment: At line waitUntilElementVisible(30, source); of addUserBySearch() method and explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)); of waitUntilElementVisible(int seconds, WebElement element) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [StaleReferenceException](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) occurs for mainly one of two reasons:

- The element has been deleted entirely.
- The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

One possible solution to your problem is to surround dragAndDrop() in a while loop, and continually try and dragAndDrop() until you succeed. So something like the following:

```
   boolean draggedAndDropped = false;
   while(!draggedAndDropped ) {
   try{
     source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("searchedUserSource")));
     destination = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("userDestination")));
     dragAndDrop(source, destination);
     draggedAndDropped  = true;
   } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
      System.out.println("StaleElementReferenceException caught, trying again");
  }
```

}

Of course its never a good idea idea to give allow a loop to loop infinitely, so you will want to incorporate a max attempts into the while loop.

Answer (score -1):

As stated by the Selenium project's [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp), a StaleElementReferenceException can be thrown for two reasons:

1. The element has been deleted entirely.
2. The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

As such, I suspect that a race condition is occurring at this point:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("userSearchField"))).sendKeys("testuser2", Keys.ENTER);
source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("searchedUserSource")));
```

After you've entered "testuser2" in the "userSearchField" WebElement you've used *Keys.ENTER* to presumably submit the search query - the problem may be occurring because WebDriver is retrieving a reference to the "searchedUserSource" WebElement before the page has fully refreshed.

To get around this, you could try using the WebElement[.submit()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#submit%28%29) method to submit the search as it blocks the WebDriver's execution until the page has finished changing (i.e. finished displaying the search result).

Below is an example of how you could implement this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("userSearchField"))).sendKeys("testuser2").submit();
source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("searchedUserSource")));
```